# How do I merge dictionaries in list that have equal value and concate values that are not equal?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, merge

there is list of dictionaries:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 2.0,
        "code" : "12345"
    },
    {
       "id" : 2.0,
       "code" : "23456"
    },
    {
       "id" : 4.0,
       "code" : "6767"
    },
    {
       "id" : 5.0,
       "code" : "567"
    },
    {
       "id" : 4.0,
       "code" : "55657"
    }
]
```

I want to merge dict that  have common id,
then i want to have this list as you see:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 2.0,
        "code" : "12345,23456"
    },
    {
        "id" : 4.0,
        "code" : "6767,55657"
    },
    {
        "id" : 5.0,
        "code" : "567"
    }
]
```

is there any faster way can check all of this in for loop ?

Comment: no it is not..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can build a dictionary that has as key your id value and the values are a list of codes with commune id, then you can build your desired output using a list comprehension:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for d in my_list:
    result[d['id']].append(d['code'])

final_list = [{'id': k, 'code': ', '.join(v)} for k, v in result.items()]

print(final_list)
```

**output:**

```
[{'id': 2.0, 'code': '12345, 23456'},
 {'id': 4.0, 'code': '6767, 55657'},
 {'id': 5.0, 'code': '567'}]
```

Comment: thanks alot.if there are other field that are  equal  in dict that have same id ,for example "name" key,how keep them?[
    {
        "id" : 2.0,
        "code" : "12345","name":"x"
    },
    {
       "id" : 2.0,
       "code" : "23456","name":"x"
    }]